# Is it possible to override parent class constant variable with different variable type?

Tags: swift

Hi I have been told by my senior developer instead of enhance the `ItemTableViewController` with additional function that going to do the sorting for me, he wants me to sub class the `ItemTableViewController` with different different `ViewModel` with type `AvatarItemTableViewModel`, I managed to subclass the `ItemTableViewController` but I can't alter the view model to `AvatarItemTableViewModel`, also this pose another question the parent class method has no context of `AvatarItemTableViewModel`, can someone please provide me some guidance, thanks.

```
public class ItemTableViewController<T>: UIViewController where T: AvatarItem {

fileprivate let viewModel: ItemTableViewModel

public init(avatarItems: [T], selectedAvatarItem: @escaping (T) -> Void, configureCell: @escaping ConfigureAvatarCell) {
    viewModel = ItemTableViewModel(avatarItems: avatarItems, selectedAvatarItem: selectedAvatarItem, configureCell: configureCell)
    super.init(nibName: .none, bundle: .none)
    configureView()
}




public class AvatarItemTableViewController<T>: ItemTableViewController where T: AvatarItem {

fileprivate let viewModel: AvatarItemTableViewModel

public init(avatarItems: [T], selectedAvatarItem: @escaping (T) -> Void, configureCell: @escaping ConfigureAvatarCell) {
   super.init(avatarItems: avatarItems, selectedAvatarItem: selectedAvatarItem, configureCell: configureCell) 
   super.viewModel = AvatarItemTableViewModel(avatarItems: avatarItems, selectedAvatarItem: selectedAvatarItem, configureCell: configureCell)


}
```

Comment: It's not possible but it should work if `AvatarItemTableViewModel` is also a subclass of `ItemTableViewModel`.

Comment: Thank you, I totally agree with you.